# Error determining IP Address for Virtual Machine; Error obtaining NIC; Failure sending request

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create windows vm in the cluster with terraform and I am facing error while creating

**Error**

> ```
> Error: Error applying plan:
>
> 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> * module.vnet.azurerm_virtual_machine.vm[0]: 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> * azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.0: Error determining IP Address for Virtual Machine "vm0" Error obtaining NIC "nic0"
> ```
>
> network.InterfacesClient#Get: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 --
>   Original Error: Get 
>        wsarecv: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>
> ```
> Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
> Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
> any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
> above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.
> ```

**terraform module i am trying**
for simplicity, I am not adding how vnet , resource group etc in following code

```
resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "tcp" {
  resource_group_name            = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  loadbalancer_id                = "${azurerm_lb.main.id}"
  name                           = "RDP-VM-${count.index}"
  protocol                       = "tcp"
  frontend_port                  = "5000${count.index + 1}"
  backend_port                   = 3389
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "pip-${var.location_id}-${var.environment}-${var.cost_centre}-${var.project}-${var.seq_id}"
  count                          = "${var.vm_count}"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "lb_rule" {
  resource_group_name            = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  loadbalancer_id                = "${azurerm_lb.main.id}"
  name                           = "lbrule-${var.location_id}-${var.environment}-${var.cost_centre}-${var.project}-${var.seq_id}"
  protocol                       = "tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 80
  backend_port                   = 80
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "pip-${var.location_id}-${var.environment}-${var.cost_centre}-${var.project}-${var.seq_id}"
  enable_floating_ip             = false
  backend_address_pool_id        = "${azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.main.id}"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes        = 5
  probe_id                       = "${azurerm_lb_probe.main.id}"
  depends_on                     = ["azurerm_lb_probe.main"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "nic${count.index}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  count               = "${var.vm_count}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                                    = "ipconfig${count.index}"
    subnet_id                               = "${azurerm_subnet.main.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation           = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_nat_rule_association" "main" {
  ip_configuration_name     = "ipconfig${count.index}"
  network_interface_id      ="${element(azurerm_network_interface.main.*.id, count.index)}"
  nat_rule_id               = "${element(azurerm_lb_nat_rule.tcp.*.id, count.index)}"
  count                     = "${var.vm_count}"
  depends_on = ["azurerm_network_interface.main","azurerm_lb_nat_rule.tcp"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "main" {
  network_interface_id      ="${element(azurerm_network_interface.main.*.id, count.index)}"
  ip_configuration_name     = "ipconfig${count.index}"
  backend_address_pool_id = "${azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.main.id}"
  count                   = "${var.vm_count}"
  depends_on = ["azurerm_network_interface.main","azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.main"]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                  = "vm${count.index}"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  availability_set_id   = "${azurerm_availability_set.main.id}"
  vm_size               = "${var.vm_size}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.main.*.id, count.index)}"]
  count                 = "${var.vm_count}"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "${var.image_publisher}"
    offer     = "${var.image_offer}"
    sku       = "${var.image_sku}"
    version   = "${var.image_version}"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name          = "osdisk${count.index}"
    create_option = "FromImage"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${var.vm_name}-${count.index}"
    admin_username = "${var.admin_username}"
    admin_password = "${var.admin_password}"
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {}
}
```

**i am using above code as module**

```
module kofax-vnet{
//some variable values
    location_id="euwest"
    location="westeurope"
    vnet_cidr_list=["10.125.0.0/16"]
    subnet_cidr="10.125.0.0/20"
    vm_count= "2"
    vm_size="Standard_B4ms"
    image_publisher="MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    image_offer="WindowsServer"
    image_sku="2016-Datacenter"
    image_version="latest"
    vm_name="myvm"
    admin_username="someuser"
    admin_password="somepassword"
}
```

Comment: the error suggests this is just a timeout?

Comment: i tried adding timeout for azurerm_virtual_machine resource but it is not supported. for smaller vm size. this code works fine but when we are trying to add large size vm it fails

Comment: Have you tried allocating the private IP address statically?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding **depends_on** in **azurerm_virtual_machine**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
//some code
      depends_on = ["azurerm_network_interface.main"]
}
```